# How to know cron job status?

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5.1, crontrigger, clickatell

I'm running cron jobs using laravel daily in that i'm sending messages to every client using clickatell api and saving the message status in the database. Here i want to get email when cron job started how many messages are sent, how many are pending and how many are failed.

Iam running my cron jobs like below

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{       
    $path = public_path().'/cron-jobs/jobs.php';         
    $schedule->command('sms:note')->cron('0 8,16 * * *')->sendOutputTo($path);
}
```

And path in unix server to run cron job every day.

```
* * * * * php /var/www/{domain}/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

How can i do this, i have searched for this but i didn't get any idea.

Please help me out!

Comment: Can you post the command contents of sms:note? This is either defined in the API itself, or in the Kernel class. Then you can modify this code by adding logging features to it.

Comment: Why not triggering the mail at the start of cron job ? Have you set the cron job in cpanel too ?